# What does it mean by "bust out a book"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Gilbert is sad and quite sensitive now because he's father passed away a few days ago and B is like an *annoying* character. *That ugly orphan* below is Anne, and Gilbert kind of likes her while B and the other boys make fun of her.

> B: Hey, Gilbert! How's it going, Blythe?
>
> G: Fine.
>
> B: You gotta come back to school, bud. That ugly orphan's out of control.
>
> G:  What do you care?
>
> B:  We need a guy to show her she's not so smart.
>
> G: She's smart. Deal with it.
>
> B: Why you gotta be like that, bud? [chuckling]
>
> G: Why don't you **bust out a book** and take care of it yourself?
>
> B: . . .Yeah, right. Good one, bud.
>
> *Anne with an E*

What does it mean by "bust out a book" here?
Does "bust out" as a whole have a different meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Bust out* is an informal expression with a few different meanings. Here, it means *take out*, as in "Why don't you **take out** a book and take care of it yourself?"

Here is a definition from Merriam-Webster:

> 2 [bust out (something) or bust (something) out](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bust%20out)   : to take (something) from the place where it is stored so that it can be used : to break out • He busted out the champagne.

Comment: I think the 'so that it can be used' part of that definition is also significant. You wouldn't say you were going to bust something out if you were just going to take it out then not use it. It implies that the thing will be taken out and then used in some way.